# PowerShell: How to accept an array of custom enum types as a function param?

Tags: powershell, parameters, enums, arguments

The example below is simply for illustration.  I'm not looking for optimization or any sort of workaround solutions as this function obviosuly doesn't do anything useful - again, it's simply for presenting:

- Accepting an entire enum type/structure as an argument
- Doing something (anything) with the passed enum argument/param.

  - In this case it simply retrieves the enum name that corresponds to the int value of 2.

The following works to accept a single enum type as an argument and outputs the expected value:

```
function EnumTest
{
    param ([System.Object]$EnumObject)
    
    BEGIN {}
    PROCESS
    {
        [System.Enum]::GetName($EnumObject, 2)
    }
    END {}
}

enum MyCustomEnum
{
    Balloon     = 1
    Bicycle     = 2
    Cloud       = 3
}

enum MyOtherCustomEnum
{
    Crayon      = 1
    Dog         = 2
    Elephant    = 3
}

EnumTest -EnumObject MyCustomEnum
```

##### Output:

```
Bicycle
```

## Questions:

1. How can I get the param $EnumObject to accept an **array** of enum *types* (the entire enum structure, not just one of its names/values), e.g.:

   EnumTest -EnumObject MyCustomEnum, MyOtherCustomEnum

   - `[System.Object[]]$EnumObject` doesn't work
   - `[System.Enum[]]$EnumObject` doesn't work

     - Why doesn't this work?
   - `[array]$EnumObject` doesn't work
2. What is the appropriate way to pass an entire enum type as an argument?

   - `EnumTest -EnumObject MyCustomEnum` appears to pass the enum structure's name "MyCustomEnum" as a string instead of the intended (entire) enum object `[MyCustomEnum]`.

Comment: An enum is a string and a number (byte, int, ...) and nothing else.  If you want somethi9ng more complicated you need another array of objects that associates the number in the array to the enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell interprets the bare word token `MyCustomEnum` in this statement:

```
EnumTest -EnumObject MyCustomEnum
```

... as a *string literal*, no different than if you'd done:

```
EnumTest -EnumObject "MyCustomEnum"
```

If you just want to pass the *type* as a parameter argument, place a type literal in a subexpression like this:

```
EnumTest -EnumObject $([MyCustomEnum])
```

`[object]`/`[System.Object]` as parameter type will work here, since every type ultimately inherits from `[object]` anyway.

If you want to restrict parameter arguments to only types, use `[type]` as the parameter type:

```
function EnumTest
{
    param (
         [type]$EnumType
    )
    
    process {
        if($EnumType.IsEnum){
            [System.Enum]::GetName($EnumObject, 2)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pass an arbitrary number of enums either as positional arguments or via the pipeline, add an appropriate `[Parameter()]` attribute and (for trailing argument support) change the parameter type to an array of `[type]`:

```
function EnumTest
{
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [type[]]$EnumType
    )
    
    process {
        foreach($type in $EnumType){
            if($type.IsEnum){
                [System.Enum]::GetName($type, 2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now all of the below invocation scenarios will work:

```
EnumTest $([MyCustomEnum]) $([MyOtherCustomEnum]) 
# or 
EnumTest @([MyCustomEnum], [MyOtherCustomEnum]) 
# or
[MyCustomEnum],[MyOtherCustomEnum] |EnumTest 
# or 
$enumTypes = [MyCustomEnum],[MyOtherCustomEnum]
EnumTest -EnumType $enumTypes
# or, if you wanna get funky: 
$paramArgs = @{ EnumType = 'MyCustomEnum,MyOtherCustomEnum' -split ',' -as [type[]] }
EnumTest @paramArgs
```

---

*A previous version of the question made it sound like the user wanted to **store** multiple enum values as a scalar value, hence this answer:*

It looks like you'll want to decorate the enum type with the `Flags` attribute - this will allow you to store *compound values*:

```
[Flags()]
enum MyCustomEnum
{
    FirstName   = 1
    SecondName  = 2
    ThirdName   = 4
}
```

Now multiple flags can be stored in a single instance of `MyCustomEnum`:

```
PS ~> $value = [MyCustomEnum]'FirstName, ThirdName'
PS ~> $value.value__ # the instance now stores the value of `FirstName -bor ThirdName`
5
```

The presence or absence of each individually defined value can be interrogated with the `Enum.HasFlag` method:

```
PS ~> $value = [MyCustomEnum]'FirstName, ThirdName'
PS ~> $value.HasFlag('FirstName')
True
PS ~> $value.HasFlag('SecondName')
False
```

Comment: @Paulπ what exactly do you mean by "enum structure"? If you want to pass the _type_ as an argument, then the parameter type should be `[type]` (although `[object]` or no explicit parameter type would work too) and you'd pass the type literal like this: `EnumTest -EnumObject $([MyCustomEnum])`

Comment: @Paulπ Yeah, I see what you mean now, I've updated my answer to show both how to pass type literals as arguments, and how to better declare your parameters for accepting types :)

Comment: Enum 'type' is more accurate.  I used 'structure' to indicate that the entire type should be passed rather than one of its names/values.  I will update my question.  Unfortunately, passing the type literal using `$([MyCustomEnum]` in tandem with a param type [System.Type[]] still doesn't allow me to pass mutliple enum types.

Comment: @Paulπ Of course it does :) You can now do `EnumTest $([MyCustomEnum]) $([MyOtherCustomEnum])` or `[MyCustomEnum],[MyOtherCustomEnum] |EnumTest` or `EnumTest -EnumType @([MyCustomEnum],[MyOtherCustomEnum])`

Comment: Apologies - I didn't see your edit and addition that uses a ForEach block.  This works.  I was hoping to restrict the param arguments to the type [System.Enum] within the param declaration itself, and use the `Process{}` block to iterate/process each one rather than do the type checking further into the function.  I'm still curious why using `[System.Enum]`, `[System.Enum[]]` or even `[System.Object[]]` as a param type doesn't work.  And also why using `[System.Type[]]` doesn't work with the `Process{}` block like I expect it to?